# Difference between all the "that" in this sentence?

Tags: american-english

I want to know the meaning all the "that" in this sentence. Are they all the same?

"He says he told the truth **that** the company misled consumers about the highly addictive nature of nicotine, **that** it ignored research indicating **that** some of the additives used to improve flavor caused cancer and **that** it had hid documents **that** could be used against the company in lawsuits brought by sick or dying smokers."

Source: Salter, C. (2009 April) **Jeffery Wigand: The Whistle Blower**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four are conjunctions. They introduce a functioning as the object of a verb. The verbs involve reported ideas

> He told that ...
>
> He indicated that ...
>
> He says that

The verb of (1) (2) and (4) is the verb "told" (in a list of objects) The verb of (3) is "indicating"

The last "that" is a relative pronoun - it introduces a clause that describes the word "documents".